# MessageDriverBean - Retry mechanism

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, message-driven-bean

I've been reading around SO and some other google results and I got confused, some say I've to call `context.setRollbackOnly();` other say it is not required as the MDB will do it by himself.

So, I've a `MessageDrivenBean` class that receives messages from a `JMS Queue`.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MyEventReceiverJMS", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/TheQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")
})
public class MyEventReceiverJMS implements MessageListener {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext context;


    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        try {
            // Some logic goes here
        } 
        catch (JMSException ex) {
            logger.error("JMSException|could not retrieve object from the message body - reason: {}", ex.getMessage());
            context.setRollbackOnly();
        } 
        catch (JSONException ex) {
            logger.error("error while creating the JSON - reason: ", ex.getMessage());
            context.setRollbackOnly();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("could not communicate with the server - reason: {}", ex.getMessage());
            context.setRollbackOnly();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, if there is an exception on the `onMessage` will the `message` (or as I call them, event) be put back on the Queue by the MDB or do I have to call `context.setRollbackOnly();` on every catch to put the message back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do I have to call context.setRollbackOnly() on every catch to put the message back ?**

It is up to us, If you want to roll back the message for all exceptions, yes.
If it is a bad/poison message, there is no meaning of rolling back the transaction, it is good idea to discard by logging exception and the payload of the message.

**For your first query, If there is an exception on the onMessage will the message be put back on the Queue, please find the points below:**

> The JMS Server could redeliver messages because of:
>
> A java.lang.Error or java.lang.RuntimeException has been thrown from
>   the Receiver/MDB’s onMessage method
>
> User has made a call to ejbcontext.setRollbackOnly() in his MDB’s
>   onMessage method (this applies to Container Managed Transaction only)
>
> MDB participating in a Transaction failed for some reason.

The below posts are really good and you can refer it for more details:

http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2011/01/10/working-with-jms-and-the-standard-issues-in-jms/